# Junit и xml файлы

Tags: java, xml, junit

Допустим, нужно протестировать функции калькулятора. В обычном случае на вход в тестах подавались бы обычные числа. А как быть, если на вход нужно дать xml-файл?

Comment: Не до конца понятен вопрос. Попробуйте привести пример кода, в котором на вход подаются обычные числа, и укажите место, в котором хотелось бы подавать XML-файл.

Answer (score 1):

Помещаете тестовый xml файлик как ресурс в тесты и передаете его в тестируемый метод. Файл можно передать как 'inputStream' или как текст.

Answer (score 0):

Не до конца понятен вопрос, но попробую ответить, так как в своих тестах тоже использую информацию из внешних файлов. Дальше идёт пример кода, который в каждом тестовом методе обеспечивает доступ к XML документу.

```
package ru.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 * Тестовое приложение, которые использует в тестах данные из XML документа.
 */
public class TestApp {
    private Document document;

    /**
     * Метод, который будет вызываться перед каждым тестом в файле.
     * Загружает и парсит необходимый XML документ.
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // Здесь можно указывать любой файл в classpath и не только.
        document = builder.parse(new File("src_test/test.xml"));
    }

    /**
     * Метод, который вызывается после каждого теста.
     * Здесь можно ничего не делать.
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        document = null;
    }

    /**
     * Сам тест.
     * Здесь получаем какую-то очень нужную информацию из XML документа.
     */
    @Test
    public void testDocument() {
        // Запрашиваем элементы data из XML документа.
        document.getElementsByTagName("data");
    }
}
```

В методе testDocument вы можете выбирать из уже загруженного XML документа необходимые для теста данные.